# 139 : Failed with error 'aborted', from rs4 to rs1

Tags: mongodb-3.4

[image]

aborted in mongodb

in logs i found

2017-09-14T01:35:21.533+0900 W SHARDING [conn38309] Chunk move failed :: caused by :: ChunkRangeCleanupPending: can't accept new chunks because there are still 4 deletes from previous migration

2017-09-14T01:35:11.439+0900 I COMMAND [conn38309] command admin.$cmd command: moveChunk { moveChunk: "transam_db.panelist", shardVersion: [ Timestamp 762000|1, ObjectId('590b4564c5ac1ee3b6e9050d') ], epoch: ObjectId('590b4564c5ac1ee3b6e9050d'), configdb: "configReplSet/mgdb07:27019,mgdb08:27019,mgdb09:27019", fromShard: "rs1", toShard: "rs4", min: { panelist_id: 407157 }, max: { panelist_id: 416836 }, chunkVersion: [ Timestamp 762000|1, ObjectId('590b4564c5ac1ee3b6e9050d') ], maxChunkSizeBytes: 67108864, waitForDelete: false, takeDistLock: false } exception: can't accept new chunks because there are still 4 deletes from previous migration code:200 numYields:75 reslen:278 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 161, w: 3 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 79, w: 3 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 79, W: 3 } } } protocol:op_command 2622ms

Could you give me any solution regarding this and i am get this after the changes we have done in set paramteters in replicasets and config servers and mongos

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, fast solution is give (at every shards PRIMARY) command rs.stepDown() what makes that PRIMARY status is moved to other node. That will release those (delete) locks. OK, result is so called orphan chunk, but that is not a problem, just little bit more diskspace usage.